# How to not lose a text field's focus when tapping other widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a single-select field with an options tray.

[Desired output when an option is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfSg1.gif)

The widget has the following structure:

```dart
// Overlay
OverlayEntry(
  child: Focus(
    parentNode: parentFocusNode,
    child: Card(child: ListView()), // Options list
  )
)

// Main widget
Focus(
  focusNode: parentFocusNode,
  child: TextField(),
)
```

The logic for displaying the options tray is:

```dart
parentFocusNode.addListener(() {
  if (parentNode.hasFocus) showOptions();
  else hideOptions();
});
```

However, when I select an option, the `parentFocusNode` loses focus. Thus, the options tray is disposed before the option's `onTap()` callback is executed.

[Option's onTap() is not being executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixxkW.gif)

Here is my widget:

```dart
class SingleSelect extends StatefulWidget {
  const SingleSelect({super.key});

  @override
  State<SingleSelect> createState() => _SingleSelectState();
}

class _SingleSelectState extends State<SingleSelect> {
  var options = ['option1', 'option2'];
  FocusNode parentFocusNode = FocusNode();
  TextEditingController textFieldController = TextEditingController();
  OverlayEntry? optionsTray;

  void showOptions() {
    optionsTray = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) {
        return Positioned(
          top: 50,
          height: 100,
          width: 200,
          child: Focus(
            parentNode: parentFocusNode,
            child: Card(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 2,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                  title: Text(options[index]),
                  onTap: () => textFieldController.text = options[index],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    Overlay.of(context).insert(optionsTray!);
  }

  void hideOptions() {
    optionsTray!.remove();
    optionsTray = null;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    parentFocusNode.addListener(() {
      if (parentFocusNode.hasFocus) {
        showOptions();
      } else {
        hideOptions();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Focus(
      focusNode: parentFocusNode,
      child: TextField(controller: textFieldController),
    );
  }
}
```

As seen in the widget's code, I tried inserting the overlay into the same focus tree by passing my main `Focus.focusNode` as a `Focus.parentNode` to the overlay. But the `parentFocusNode` still loses focus when an option is selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To control the events happening after a click outside of a textfield, there is a property called [`TextField.onTapOutside`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onTapOutside.html) wherein you can define what happens after the user clicks outside of the textfield. This also prevents the textfield from losing focus.

Another solution is wrapping the widgets you're interacting with as a [`TextFieldTapRegion`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextFieldTapRegion-class.html). This will prevent focus loss on tapping whatever is wrapped with a `TextFieldTapRegion`.